# How to get partial cumulative sums (of positive and negative numbers) in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, cumulative-sum

I have an array with positive and negative numbers and want to do a cumulative sum of numbers of the same sign until the next number carries an opposite sign. It starts again at 0. Maybe better explained with a sample.
Here is the original array:

```
np.array([0.2, 0.5, 1.3, 0.6, -0.3, -1.1, 0.2, -2.0, 0.7, 1.1, 0.0, -1.2])
```

And the output I expect **without** using a loop, of course:

```
np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.6, 0.0, -1.4, 0.2, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.8, -1.2])
```

Any efficient idea would help a lot...

Comment: Do you use that output format directly?

Comment: how do you handle 0s? As positive numbers?

Comment: 0 are positive, as in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One vectorial option:

```
a = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 1.3, 0.6, -0.3, -1.1, 0.2, -2.0, 0.7, 1.1, 0.0, -1.2])

cs = np.cumsum(a)
idx = np.nonzero(np.r_[np.diff(a>0), True])
out = np.zeros_like(a)

out[idx] = np.diff(np.r_[0, cs[idx]])
```

Output:

```
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2.6,  0. , -1.4,  0.2, -2. ,  0. ,  1.8,  0. ,  -1.2])
```

Comment: Thank you mozway, it works as expected.
How would you handle the last element in the a array (-1.2) so that it appears in the out array?

Comment: Thank you mozway, it works with my original data and with 
a = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 1.3, 0.6, -0.3, -1.1, 0.2, -2.0, 0.7, 1.1, 0.0, -1.2, -1.6]).

Unfortunately, it does not work if the last 2 numbers have a different sign as in :
a = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 1.3, 0.6, -0.3, -1.1, 0.2, -2.0, 0.7, 1.1, 0.0, -1.2, 1.6])

I can add a 0 at the end, after 1.6, it works. Later on I can remove it in the out, but I suspect there is a smarter approach...

Comment: @tibibou can you check again?